# Lots of small collections affecting GC - iterator vs stream vs loop

Tags: for-loop, optimization, iterator, garbage-collection, java-stream

I have a system that has a lot of small collections that are being iterated and modified (specifically [this library code](https://github.com/conveyal/r5/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/conveyal/r5/streets/StreetRouter.java#L625)), which results in a TB of memory in the profiler. I am finding that GC is running too much on smaller instances due to this. I am about to try some tests (however they take a fair amount of time - so asking here also - and if there is anything else I might be missing) of using a `for` loop (with a modified index since it removes - then versus a storage of which to remove in `finally`) - as well as a test with a `stream` (maybe even a `spliterator`?). Ultimately, is one solution better in instantiation reduction (to cull GC overhead)?

Note that yes we can increase the instance size, but we are finding that CPU is often <10% and are trying to bring down the memory so that we can even out memory and CPU.

Comment: You can not modify a collection with the Stream API. It’s not clear what “versus a storage of which to remove in finally” is supposed to mean. Letting aside that an index based loop calling remove is a performance disaster for most list implementations, both, collection manipulations and garbage collection, are CPU intense operations. So if your CPU load is below 10%, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Holger I can only say at the moment that the entire execution time in the profiler is 2hrs 30 min and half of it is GC Pause...

Comment: When you have a long GC pause but a low CPU load, the issue is not the workload given to the garbage collector. I suppose you would know if you had configured the GC to use only one CPU core. So if we can preclude that, check whether there is something else (other processes or the kernel itself) blocking the JVM process or whether there are lots of page faults or even swapping going on.